# Purposefully Slow MATLAB Function?

Tags: debugging, matlab, performance, distributed-computing

I want to write a really, really, slow program for [MATLAB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB). I'm talking like, O(2^n) or worse. It has to finish, and it has to be deterministically slow, so no "if rand() = 123,123, exit!" This sounds crazy, but it's actually for a distributed systems test. I need to create a .m file, compile it (with [MCC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MCC#Technology)), and then run it on my distributed system to perform some debugging operations.

The program must constantly be doing work, so `sleep()` is not a valid option.

I tried making a random large matrix and finding its inverse, but this was completing too quickly. Any ideas?

Comment: surely just take anything that's at all slow (like your matrix inversion) and do it many, many times?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This naive implementation of the Discrete Fourier Transform takes ~ 9 seconds for a 2048 long input vector x on my 1.86 GHz single core machine.  Going to 4096 inputs extends the time to ~ 35 seconds, close to the 4x I would expect for O(N^2).  I don't have the patience to try longer inputs :)

```
function y = SlowDFT(x)

t = cputime;
y = zeros(size(x));
for c1=1:length(x)
    for c2=1:length(x)
        y(c1) = y(c1) + x(c2)*(cos((c1-1)*(c2-1)*2*pi/length(x)) - ...
                            1j*sin((c1-1)*(c2-1)*2*pi/length(x)));
    end
end
disp(cputime-t);
```

**EDIT:** Or if you're looking to stress memory more than CPU:

```
function y = SlowDFT_MemLookup(x)

t = cputime;
y = zeros(size(x));
cosbuf = cos((0:1:(length(x)-1))*2*pi/length(x));
for c1=1:length(x)
    cosctr = 1;
    sinctr = round(3*length(x)/4)+1;
    for c2=1:length(x)
         y(c1) = y(c1) + x(c2)*(cosbuf(cosctr) ...
                            -1j*cosbuf(sinctr));
         cosctr = cosctr + (c1-1);
         if cosctr > length(x), cosctr = cosctr - length(x); end
         sinctr = sinctr + (c1-1);
         if sinctr > length(x), sinctr = sinctr - length(x); end
    end
end
disp(cputime-t);
```

This is faster than calculating sin and cos on each iteration.  A 2048 long input took ~ 3 seconds, and a 16384 long input took ~ 180 seconds.

Answer (score 4):

Count to 2<sup>n</sup>. Optionally, make a slow function call in each iteration.

Answer (score 4):

If you want real work that's easy to set up and stresses CPU way over memory:

- Large dense matrix inversion (not slow enough? make it bigger.)
- Factor an [RSA number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsa_challenge)

Answer (score 3):

How about using inv? It has been [reported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1419580/why-is-matlabs-inv-slow-and-inaccurate) to be quite slow.

Comment: Then try a 10000000x10000000 matrix

Answer (score 2):

I don't speak MATLAB but something equivalent to the following might work.

```
loops = 0
counter = 0
while (loops < MAX_INT) {
    counter = counter + 1;
    if (counter == MAX_INT) {
        loops = loops + 1;
        counter = 0;
    }
}
```

This will iterate MAX_INT*MAX_INT times. You can put some computationally heavy thing in the loop for it to take longer if this is not enough.

Comment: This is especially good as loops in MATLAB are notoriously slow and it's possible to control exactly how long your slow code is.

Comment: @David J: The idea that MATLAB is slow with loops, while once true, is not so much anymore. The JIT that we added a few years ago really changed this.

Comment: Well, new versions may be faster, but loops in matlab are still several orders of magnitude slower than those in C-like or java-like platforms.  Course, if you want a more "notorious" level of slow, just use function calls...

Answer (score 2):

Do some work in a loop.  You can tune the time it takes to complete using the number of loop iterations.

Answer (score 2):

Easy! Go back to your Turing machine roots and think of processes that are O(2^n) or worse.

Here's a fairly simple one (warning, untested but you get the point)

```
N = 12; radix = 10;
odometer = zeros(N, 1);
done = false;
while (~done)
    done = true;
    for i = 1:N
        odometer(i) = odometer(i) + 1;
        if (odometer(i) >= radix)
            odometer(i) = 0;
        else
            done = false;
            break;
        end
    end
end
```

Even better, how about calculating Fibonacci numbers recursively? Runtime is O(2^N), since fib(N) has to make two function calls fib(N-1) and fib(N-2), but stack depth is O(N), since only one of those function calls happens at a time.

```
function y = fib(n)
   if (n <= 1)
      y = 1;
   else
      y = fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);
   end
end
```

Comment: You mixed up + and *.  Not that that matters much, given the context ;-).

Comment: ? neither of those functions should have a multiply; the odometer is only an increment, and fibonacci is additive.

Answer (score 1):

You could ask it to `factor(X)` for a suitably large X

Comment: `factor(X)` for a suitably large prime `X` may or may not be slower.

Comment: For large X with certain properties, it will be heavy work with minimal effort in setting up the problem. Unlikely to be O(2^n), but he just needs something slow.

Comment: And for large X with certain properties it will be trivially easy. For instance any X that == 2^n will factor in no time at all. This is why I recommend a prime or pseudoprime. There are lists of either on Google.

Comment: Well, I presume he's smart enough to at least try whatever integer he picks first

Answer (score 1):

You could also test if a given input is prime by just dividing it by all smaller numbers. This would give you O(n^2).

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
tic
isprime( primes(99999999) );
toc
```

---

**EDIT**:

For a more extensive set of tests, use these benchmarks (perhaps for multiple repetitions even):

```
disp(repmat('-',1,85))
disp(['MATLAB Version ' version])
disp(['Operating System: ' system_dependent('getos')])
disp(['Java VM Version: ' version('-java')]);
disp(['Date: ' date])
disp(repmat('-',1,85))

N = 3000;   % matrix size
A = rand(N,N);  
A = A*A;

tic;  A*A; t=toc;
fprintf('A*A \t\t\t%f sec\n', t)

tic; [L,U,P] = lu(A); t=toc; clear L U P
fprintf('LU(A)\t\t\t%f sec\n', t)

tic; inv(A); t=toc;
fprintf('INV(A)\t\t\t%f sec\n', t)

tic; [U,S,V] = svd(A); t=toc; clear U S V
fprintf('SVD(A)\t\t\t%f sec\n', t)

tic; [Q,R,P] = qr(A); t=toc; clear Q R P
fprintf('QR(A)\t\t\t%f sec\n', t)

tic; [V,D] = eig(A); t=toc; clear V D
fprintf('EIG(A)\t\t\t%f sec\n', t)

tic; det(A); t=toc;
fprintf('DET(A)\t\t\t%f sec\n', t)

tic; rank(A); t=toc;
fprintf('RANK(A)\t\t\t%f sec\n', t)

tic; cond(A); t=toc;
fprintf('COND(A)\t\t\t%f sec\n', t)

tic; sqrtm(A); t=toc;
fprintf('SQRTM(A)\t\t%f sec\n', t)

tic; fft(A(:)); t=toc;
fprintf('FFT\t\t\t%f sec\n', t)

tic; isprime(primes(10^7)); t=toc;
fprintf('Primes\t\t\t%f sec\n', t)
```

The following are the results on my machine using N=1000 for one iteration only (note primes is using as upper bound 10^7 NOT 10^8 [takes way more time!])

```
A*A             0.178329 sec
LU(A)           0.118864 sec
INV(A)          0.319275 sec
SVD(A)          15.236875 sec
QR(A)           0.841982 sec
EIG(A)          3.967812 sec
DET(A)          0.121882 sec
RANK(A)         1.813042 sec
COND(A)         1.809365 sec
SQRTM(A)        22.750331 sec
FFT             0.113233 sec
Primes          27.080918 sec
```

Answer (score 1):

this will run 100% cpu for WANTED_TIME seconds

```
WANTED_TIME = 2^n; % seconds
t0=cputime; 
t=cputime; 
while (t-t0 < WANTED_TIME)
    t=cputime; 
end;
```