# Code Analyzer: INV is slow and inaccurate

Tags: matlab, linear-algebra, numerical-methods, matrix-inverse

When I try to calculate a matrix inverse using Matlab's inv() operation:

```
A = rand(10,10);
b = rand(10,1);

C = inv(A);
D = C*b;
```

I get the following warning at the last row: INV is slow and inaccurate. Use A\b for INV(A)*b , and b/A for b*INV(A).

I can change the code above into:

```
A = rand(10,10);
b = rand(10,1);

C = inv(A);
D = A\b;
```

Now I don't get the warning, but I don't think this solution is better.

Note: I need to store both the inverse of matrix A as well as inv(A)*c. Also, in my real file the size of matrix A can be 5000 x 5000 or even bigger.

Are there any better solutions in terms of efficiency and accuracy or is the first method fine?

Comment: Related: [Why is Matlab's inv slow and inaccurate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1419580/why-is-matlabs-inv-slow-and-inaccurate)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should listen to Matlab and use the second option. `inv(A)*b` and `A\b` are computed with different algorithms under the hood, and `\` is indeed more accurate.

The [documentation for `inv`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inv.html) states:

> In practice, it is seldom necessary to form the explicit inverse of a matrix. A frequent misuse of inv arises when solving the system of linear equations Ax = b. One way to solve this is with x = inv(A)*b. A better way, from both an execution time and numerical accuracy standpoint, is to use the matrix division operator x = A\b. This produces the solution using Gaussian elimination, without forming the inverse. See mldivide () for further information.

Comment: I'v same Problem, I used both `/` and `\` but couldn't resolve my case, not getting accurate value. Also I only want first index only, i.e `ans(1)` . My code: `inv(-[40 200;1 -1])*(0.9*(2-200))`

Answer (score 3):

If you absolutely need the inverse later on, then you have to compute it. If you can use the backslash operator (`\`) instead of an inverse again later on, I would stay away from the inverse and listen to MATLAB's suggestion.  For numerical reasons, it is always better to use a slash operator when you can, so the second approach is better even though it is slower.

Comment: I agree. Also, `tic`-`toc` showed that the second approach is slower: `0.0851` against `0.1284`

Comment: @rascob The second option is slower because it is doing more work (inv and \ ), but \ gives a more accurate answer.

Comment: @shoelzer Sure, wasn't surprised by the result :) Just wanted to show that, since inv(A) will be needed anyhow, the first approach is indeed faster.

Comment: @rascob Right. But even if `inv(A)` is needed at some point, it's not needed here. I think it's always better use `A\b` if possible.

Answer (score 3):

Some additional information:

If you are to calculate

```
Ax = b
```

For many different `b`'s, but with a constant `A`, you might want to pre-factorize `A`. That is:

```
[L U P] = lu(A);
x = (U \ (L \ ( P * b)));
```

Don't know about other fields, but this occurs frequently in power system engineering at least.