# Why is the output of inv() and pinv() not equal in Matlab and Octave?

Tags: matlab, precision, floating-accuracy, matrix-inverse, numerical-analysis

I have noticed that if A is a NxN matrix and it has the inverse matrix. But what the inv() and pinv() function output is different.
 - My environment is Win7x64 SP1, Matlab R2012a, Cygwin Octave 3.6.4, FreeMat 4.2

Have a look at the examples from Octave:

```
A = rand(3,3)
A =
0.185987   0.192125   0.046346
0.140710   0.351007   0.236889
0.155899   0.107302   0.300623

pinv(A) == inv(A)
ans =
0 0 0
0 0 0
0 0 0
```

- It's all the same `ans` result by running the same command above in Matlab.

---

- And I calculate `inv(A)*A` or `A*inv(A)`, the result is identity 3x3 matrix in both Octave and Matlab.
- The result of `A*pinv(A)` and `pinv(A)*A` are identity 3x3 matrix in Matlab and FreeMat.
- The result of `A*pinv(A)` is identity 3x3 matrix in Octave.
- The result of `pinv(A)*A` is *not* identity 3x3 matrix in Octave.

---

I don't know the reason why `inv(A) != pinv(A)`, I have considered the details of the element in the matrix. It seems to be the floating accuracy problem which causes this problem.

The 10+ digits after the dot point may be different like this:

- `6.65858991579923298331777914427220821380615200000000` element in `inv(A)(1,1)` against
- `6.65858991579923209513935944414697587490081800000000` element in `pinv(A)(1,1)`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is Matlab's inv slow and inaccurate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1419580/why-is-matlabs-inv-slow-and-inaccurate)

Comment: @Shai, I believe OP might benefit from reading the answers to the question you linked to (at least if OP is using `inv` for solving `x = A^-1*b`), but IMO this is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 16):

This question is quite old, but I'll answer it anyway because it appears almost on top in some google searches.

I'll use for my example the magic(N) function which returns an N-by-N magic square.

I'll create a 3x3 magic square M3, take the pseudoinverse PI_M3 and multiply them:

```
   prompt_$ M3 = magic(3) , PI_M3 = pinv(M3) , M3 * PI_M3
```

```
  M3 =

    8   1   6
    3   5   7
    4   9   2

  PI_M3 =

     0.147222  -0.144444   0.063889
    -0.061111   0.022222   0.105556
    -0.019444   0.188889  -0.102778

  ans =

     1.0000e+00  -1.2212e-14   6.3283e-15
     5.5511e-17   1.0000e+00  -2.2204e-16
    -5.9952e-15   1.2268e-14   1.0000e+00
```

As you can see the answer is the identity matrix save for some rounding errors.
I'll repeat the operation with a 4x4 magic square:

```
   prompt_$ M4 = magic(4) , PI_M4 = pinv(M4) , M4 * PI_M4
```

```
 
  M4 =

     16    2    3   13
      5   11   10    8
      9    7    6   12
      4   14   15    1

  PI_M4 =

     0.1011029  -0.0738971  -0.0613971   0.0636029
    -0.0363971   0.0386029   0.0261029   0.0011029
     0.0136029  -0.0113971  -0.0238971   0.0511029
    -0.0488971   0.0761029   0.0886029  -0.0863971

  ans =

     0.950000  -0.150000   0.150000   0.050000
    -0.150000   0.550000   0.450000   0.150000
     0.150000   0.450000   0.550000  -0.150000
     0.050000   0.150000  -0.150000   0.950000
```

The result is not the identity matrix, it means that the 4x4 magic square does not have an inverse.
I can verify this by trying one of the rules of the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse:

```
   prompt_$ M4 * PI_M4 * M4
```

```
  
ans =

   16.00000    2.00000    3.00000   13.00000
    5.00000   11.00000   10.00000    8.00000
    9.00000    7.00000    6.00000   12.00000
    4.00000   14.00000   15.00000    1.00000
```

The rule A*B*A = A is satisfied. This shows that pinv returns the inverse matrix when it is available and the pseudoinverse when the inverse is not available. This is the reason why in some situations you get a small difference, just some rounding errors, and in other situations you get a bigger difference. 
To show it I'll get the inverse of both magic quadrants and subtract them from the pseudoinverse:

```
   prompt_$ I_M3 = inv(M3) , I_M4 = inv(M4) , DIFF_M3 = PI_M3 - I_M3, DIFF_M4 = PI_M4 - I_M4
```

```
  I_M3 =

     0.147222  -0.144444   0.063889
    -0.061111   0.022222   0.105556
    -0.019444   0.188889  -0.102778

  warning: inverse: matrix singular to machine precision, rcond = 1.30614e-17
  I_M4 =

     9.3825e+13   2.8147e+14  -2.8147e+14  -9.3825e+13
     2.8147e+14   8.4442e+14  -8.4442e+14  -2.8147e+14
    -2.8147e+14  -8.4442e+14   8.4442e+14   2.8147e+14
    -9.3825e+13  -2.8147e+14   2.8147e+14   9.3825e+13

  DIFF_M3 =

     4.7184e-16  -1.0270e-15   5.5511e-16
    -9.9226e-16   2.0470e-15  -1.0825e-15
     5.2042e-16  -1.0270e-15   4.9960e-16

  DIFF_M4 =

    -9.3825e+13  -2.8147e+14   2.8147e+14   9.3825e+13
    -2.8147e+14  -8.4442e+14   8.4442e+14   2.8147e+14
     2.8147e+14   8.4442e+14  -8.4442e+14  -2.8147e+14
     9.3825e+13   2.8147e+14  -2.8147e+14  -9.3825e+13
```

Answer (score 9):

It seems to me like you answered your own question in the bottom here. The reason is floating point arithmetic. The algortihms for `inv()` and `pinv()` are not exactly the same, as `pinv()` must be able to handle non-square matrices. Therefore the answers will not be exactly the same.

If you look at the value of `pinv(A)*A`, you will see that it's very very close to the identity matrix.

I get:

```
ans =

   1.0000e+00   6.1062e-16  -3.0809e-15
  -5.8877e-15   1.0000e+00   6.3942e-15
   2.4425e-15  -3.0184e-16   1.0000e+00
```

Instead of comparing the matrices with `==`, use `< tolerance_limit`

```
c = A*pinv(A);
d = pinv(A)*A;

(c-d) < 1e-10
```

**Sidenote:**

`x = A^-1*b` should not be solved `x = inv(A)*b;`, but rather `x = A \ b;` See [the link Shai posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1419580/why-is-matlabs-inv-slow-and-inaccurate) for explanations.

Comment: What I meant to be is that pinv(A)*A should be identity matrix while now the Octave don't give me this answer, I know why this tiny result comes out, but shouldn't we always get matrix multipy it's inverse matrix equal to identity matrix just like that the Matlab and Freemat now is doing?

Comment: What does Octave give you? I guess a result _very close_ to the identity matrix (as my example). To understand why this is, Daniel's answer is quite explanatory. Octave first calculates the inverse than multiplies with the original matrix. If you get something completely different, please give an example.

Comment: I get the ans matrix just similar to your ans in your answer. What I mean is that as a product or say as a library, the Octave should let pinv(A)*A=identity matrix which make sense, but now the ans matrix it returns back doesn't make sense, and pinv(A)*A equals to identity matrix in Matlab and FreeMat.

Comment: @myme5261314 The inverse is probably calculated differently in Octave, Matlab and FreeMat, therefore the answers differ. It makes sense if you consider it as two separate calculations, first calculate the inverse of `A`, then multiply it by `A`. As the first calculation is not accurate, the answer won't either. Octave doesn't recognize `pinv(A)*A` as the identity matrix (as we do mathematically), it actually does the calculations.

Answer (score 2):

Floating point arithmetic has a certain precision, you can not rely on equality. To avoid such errors, you could try to work with the symbolic toolbox of matlab.

Very simple line of code in octave to demonstrate the problems:

```
>>> (1/48)*48==(1/49)*49
ans = 0
>>> (1/48)*48-(1/49)*49
ans =  1.1102e-16
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

I computed the pseudo-inverse matrix of `A=[1,1,0;1,0,1;2,1,1]` (which is of rank 2) by using `pinv(A)`.  `A*pinv(A)` gives a non-identity matrix, which is `A*pinv(A)=[0.667, -0.333, 0.333; -0.333, 0.667,0.333; 0.333, 0.333, 0.667]`. I think for singular matrices, it is better to compute the pseudo-inverse matrix using `svd()` manually.

Here is some update: `A*pinv(A)` itself may be different to identity matrix because of it is non-full rank. It may not depends on the Matlab algorithm of `pinv(A)`.

Comment: `A` has no inverse, which means you cannot find a matrix `B` such that `A*B` is the identity matrix. So it is no wonder than `A*pinv(A)` is not the identity matrix.